# unset $HOME but '~' works has home anyway why?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, cd, unset

## Doing my own shell

Hello, I'm doing my own version of shell and comparing it to **bash** (School Project). I noticed that when i run the following command `unset HOME; cd` or `unset HOME; cd $HOME` it says:

```
bash: cd: HOME not set
```

Okay all good for me but.. with this command `cd ~` bash goes to my home dir or when i run `echo ~` it prints my home dir.

So how do you guys deal with this? I just coded it in a way that says:

```
bash: cd: HOME not set
```

Comment: How exactly is this a problem?

Comment: _So how do you guys deal with this problem_  : I rarely fall into the temptation to implement my own shell, but if I would, I would perhaps invent my own _home_-mechanism, and not caring how other shells do it.

Comment: School project. It will be compared with BASH so i need to code it according to BASH. @tripleee if they tell me that i need to reproduce bash's behavior  this is indeed something that i need to pay attention to..

Comment: That makes sense per se, but still doesn't reveal how this is a problem. If I were to judge that, I would call it undefined implementation-specific behavior and not particularly care.

Comment: Also, I would use a properly POSIX-compatible shell rather than Bash as the yardstick; reimplementing all of Bash seems like a rather gargantuan task, and pretty pointless for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the `man` page for `bash`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html): (emphasis added)

#### Tilde Expansion

If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of
the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all
characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a
tilde-prefix.  If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are
quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde
are treated as a possible login name.  If this login name is the
null string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the shell
parameter HOME.  **If HOME is unset, the home directory of the user
executing the shell is substituted instead.**  Otherwise, the
tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated with
the specified login name.